# How do I ensure the backend call will only be made after setState runs?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In the project I'm currently working on there are a few of these:

```
const SelectOptions = ({
    defaultValue,
    label,
    name,
    options,
    onChangeFilter,
    multiple,
    onCloseFilter
  }) => {
    const [option, setOption] = useState(defaultValue);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      setOption(defaultValue);
    }, [defaultValue]);
  
    const onChangeOption = event => {
      const { value } = event.target;
      setOption(value);
      onChangeFilter(name, value);
    };
  
    return (
      <FormControl size="small" variant="outlined" fullWidth>
        <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
        <Select
          label={label}
          value={option}
          onChange={onChangeOption}
          multiple={multiple}
          renderValue={selected => (multiple ? selected.join(', ') : selected)}
          MenuProps={{
            getContentAnchorEl: null
          }}
          onClose={() => onCloseFilter() }
        >
          {!multiple && <MenuItem value="">Select</MenuItem>}
  
          {options.map(item => (
            <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
              {multiple && <Checkbox checked={option.includes(item)} />}
              <ListItemText primary={item} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
  };
```

These calls the next two functions in the parent component:

```
const onChangeFilter = (name, value) => {
    setFilters(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
};

const onCloseFilter = () => {
    fetchData();
};
```

I want to set all the filters and only when I close the `<Select />` that the backend call should be made in order to apply the filters. This is done through this function:

```
const fetchData = () => {

    const payload = { data: { id: record.id }, filter: { ...filters } };

    mutate(
      { type: 'fetchData', resource: 'data', payload },
      {
        onSuccess: (response) => {
          setData(response.data);
        },
        onFailure: () => {
          notify('ra.notification.http_error');
        }
      }
    )
};
```

Problem is that `fetchData()` is running before `setFilters(...)` finishes. I can't run `fetchData()` inside `onChangeFilter` because it would result in too many requests.

How do I ensure `fetchData()` will only run after I close the `<Select />` and after `setFilters(...)` update all my filters with the options I chose?

Comment: I suppose we'd need to see the implementation of this `Select` component to know what it does with the props passed to it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Some inputs can use the `onBlur` event handler to do "things" when the input loses focus. It's unclear what `onClose` means without more context. Can you add the `Select` component code to your question?

Comment: @DrewReese I added the `Select` component without proprietary code.